# How to expand this recurrence?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

Here is a recurrence relation I have derived:

$$E(Y_{r+1}^2) = E(Y_{r}^2) + 2E(Y_1)E(Y_r) + E(Y_1^2)$$

How can I get it in terms of $E(Y_1)$ and $E(Y_1^2)$?

I've expanded the first few terms and I'm having trouble seeing a pattern. Is there some trick to it?

I have a formula for $E(Y_r) = E(Y_1) + \frac{r}{p}$.

I'm trying to solve for variance (of $Y_r$) which is why I am in this mess.

Comment: Can you give some more details? It seems like $Y_{r+1} = Y_{r} + Y_1$ with $Y_1$ and $Y_r$ independent. There might be an easier way of doing this without ever needing to evaluate $\mathbb{E}[Y_{r+1}^2]$.

Comment: $Y_r$ is the position of your $r$ success in an infinite sequence of Bernoulli(p) trials @sudeep5221 . I've found $E(Y_r)$ and plan to solve it for the expectation, but I also need to find $Var(Y_r)$ for any $r$

Comment: If that's the case, then $Y_r = \sum_{i = 1}^r X_i$, where $X_i$'s are all independent  geometrically distributed random variables with parameter $p$. Variance of $Y_r$ is simply the sum of the variances of $X_i$'s.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems like the first step is to write
$$\operatorname{E}[Y_{r+1}^2] = \operatorname{E}[Y_r^2] + 2\operatorname{E}[Y_1](\operatorname{E}[Y_1] + \tfrac{r}{p}) + \operatorname{E}[Y_1^2]. \tag{1}$$
To simplify the notation, let's define
$$a_r = \operatorname{E}[Y_r^2], \quad c = \frac{2\operatorname{E}[Y_1]}{p}. \tag{2}$$
Note $c$ is a constant with respect to $r$.
Then the recursion $(1)$ becomes
$$a_{r+1} = a_r + cr + 2\operatorname{E}[Y_1]^2 + a_1, \tag{3}$$ which then suggests letting
$$b = a_1 + 2\operatorname{E}[Y_1]^2 = \operatorname{E}[Y_1^2] + 2\operatorname{E}[Y_1]^2.  \tag{4}$$
So now $(3)$ becomes
$$a_{r+1} = a_r + cr + b. \tag{5}$$
There are a number of ways to solve this recurrence; one way is to write out a few terms and guess the pattern:
$$\begin{align}
a_2 &= a_1 + c + b \\
a_3 &= a_2 + 2c + b = a_1 + 3c + 2b \\
a_4 &= a_3 + 3c + b = a_1 + 6c + 3b \\
a_5 &= a_4 + 4c + b = a_1 + 10c + 4b \\
&\vdots
\end{align}$$
at which point we can surmise that
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[Y_r^2] = a_r 
&= a_1 + \frac{r(r-1)}{2} c + (r-1) b \\
&= \operatorname{E}[Y_1^2] + \frac{r(r-1)}{p} \operatorname{E}[Y_1] + (r-1) (\operatorname{E}[Y_1^2] + 2 \operatorname{E}[Y_1]^2)\\
&= r \operatorname{E}[Y_1^2] + (r-1) \operatorname{E}[Y_1] \left(\frac{r}{p} + 2 \operatorname{E}[Y_1]\right). \tag{6}
\end{align}$$
I leave it to you to check that $(6)$ satisfies $(1)$.  Whether this actually reflects your model, I don't know.